# Python: Installing JCC on Windows

Tags: python, windows, pylucene, jcc

I'm trying to install PyLucene on a 64-bit Windows machine and the first thing I need to do is install JCC. On the installation page it says I need to change the `INCLUDES`, `CFLAGS`, `DEBUG_CFLAGS`, `LFLAGS` and `JAVAC` values in the `setup.py` file.

I have no idea how to do this (I've no idea what the first four even are). I've searched both online and on this site and I still haven't been able to make heads or tails of it. I'm very sorry if this is a very general question but even some tips on where to look would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I'd punt on that one. Those are C/C++ compiler options. If you're on Windows and don't recognize them, then you're in for a very steep learning curve. Perhaps using the work of a fairly popular/respected/trusted Python contributor is a reasonable alternative? I'm speaking of [Christoph Gohlke's Unofficial Windows Binaries](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/). There's one for [jcc](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#jcc).